# Giving less weight to data coming from another dataset that is noisy

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, nlp, pytorch

I have two datasets, one with clean data and one with dirty data. I train a Roberta model on the clean dataset and then get predictions for the dirty dataset. Those predictions with a probability greater than 0.9 go to the clean dataset. I then retrain the Roberta model with this new dataset (clean + dirty moving to clean).

For the retraining I am using the MAE loss function (more robust to noisy labels) and I use weights to give less value to the data that passes from the dirty to the clean dataset, as follows:

```
loss = torch.mean(torch.abs(y_true - y_pred) * weights)
```

Initially I am using an arbitrary weight of 0.5 for all the dirty data that gets passed into the clean dataset. However, I would like to assign them a weight in a more academic way, not so arbitrary.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Out of curiosity, why not use cleanlab to find the label errors and other data issues in your dataset for you directly? https://github.com/cleanlab/cleanlab

It handles most data issues for ML in a few lines of code, some examples:

### Find label issues in 1 line of code

```py
from cleanlab.classification import CleanLearning
from cleanlab.filter import find_label_issues

# Option 1 - works with sklearn-compatible models - just input the data and labels ツ
label_issues_info = CleanLearning(clf=sklearn_compatible_model).find_label_issues(data, labels)

# Option 2 - works with ANY ML model - just input the model's predicted probabilities
ordered_label_issues = find_label_issues(
    labels=labels,
    pred_probs=pred_probs,  # out-of-sample predicted probabilities from any model
    return_indices_ranked_by='self_confidence',
)
```

### Train a model as if the dataset did not have errors -- 3 lines of code

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from cleanlab.classification import CleanLearning

cl = CleanLearning(clf=LogisticRegression())  # any sklearn-compatible classifier
cl.fit(train_data, labels)

# Estimate the predictions you would have gotten if you trained without mislabeled data.
predictions = cl.predict(test_data)
```

- Journal of AI Research (with theory to prove it works): https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.00068publication
- errors found using cleanlab: https://labelerrors.com/
- Documentation and runnable tutorials for cleanlab: https://docs.cleanlab.ai/

Answer (score 1):

One way to choose the weight is based on your confidence in the dirty data and assign the weight accordingly. For example, if you think that 90% of dirty data is labeled correctly, then choosing 0.9 as the weight for the noisy data is a reasonable option.

Additionally, there is a whole literature on learning from noisy labels, you can check this survey for more information: https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.08199